# How to set up Amazon SES to send and receive emails

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp

Is there an option using Amazon's AWS services to send and receive emails?  I only see an option to send emails via SES.  If not, can someone pls suggest a free email service to create email accounts to send and receive via smtp through gmail?

Comment: SES is a service provided by AWS to send emails. Look at this link for more information : http://aws.amazon.com/ses/getting-started/

Comment: But, I also need an option to receive emails.  Can you please suggest something that has both send and receive for businesses that doesn't charge?

Comment: I see online the using AWS Route 53 may be an option to configured to send and receive emails from myemail@mydomai.com.  Any suggestions on that?

Comment: where do you see it can be set to "receive emails"?

Comment: I see it on this forum post.  Trying to figure out how.  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=360877

Comment: SES can now receive e-mails, see:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way, it will only send email:

> Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES) is a cost-effective **outbound-only** email-sending service

Comment: Can you please recommend a free email service that is good for startups?

Comment: No, Google Apps used to be free, it isn't any more. Still, they only ask about 5$/month/user, and there are other solutions (one of them on AWS - see WorkMail) with similar pricing. I would go for one of these.

Comment: SES can now receive emails too:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html