# How to create Email like "info@domain.com" and send and receive email in aws amazon

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I am trying since a last few weeks to setup an email, for example,info@domainname.com, in aws Amazon SES
I tried some of the links:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email.html
- I even went through a similar question marked closed on Stack Overflow:
  [How to set up Amazon SES to send and receive emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852576/how-to-set-up-amazon-ses-to-send-and-receive-emails)

But couldn't finish the setup correctly. Would anyone please help me to finish this task?

For your reference, I am using Free tier AWS account and have the domain attached to my Godaddy account.

Comment: You need to provide some additional information. Are you trying to send/receive email like Google Apps/Office 365/Zoho mail? Are you trying to send/receive transactional email (i.e when a user registers you want to send an email from info@example.com)? What difficulties did you find following the links you indicated?

Comment: No i am not trying like Google Apps/Office 365/Zoho mail. yes i want to send/receive transactional email.

Comment: OK. You say you couldn't finish the setup. What specific issues are you finding?

Comment: Note that the closed question you cited dates back from before SES introduced the ability to receive inbound mail.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to send and receive emails, what do you mean ?

Generally SES is used to send emails from an app that you run and you want this service to handle all the posting for you, [from doc - why use Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html)

> Building a large-scale email solution is often a complex and costly
>   challenge for a business. You must deal with infrastructure challenges
>   such as email server management, network configuration, and IP address
>   reputation. Additionally, many third-party email solutions require
>   contract and price negotiations, as well as significant up-front
>   costs. Amazon SES eliminates these challenges and enables you to
>   benefit from the years of experience and sophisticated email
>   infrastructure Amazon.com has built to serve its own large-scale
>   customer base.

The receiving part as noted in [doc](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#receipt-rules:)

> When you use Amazon SES to receive messages on behalf of your verified
>   domains, you can configure Amazon SES to deliver your messages to an
>   Amazon S3 bucket, call your custom code via an AWS Lambda function, or
>   publish notifications to Amazon SNS. You can also configure Amazon SES
>   to drop or bounce messages you do not want to receive.

so on receipt, SES will trigger rules that you have defined.

From your question, it sounds like you want to use a basic email client to do sending/receiving of emails, in this case Amazon provides another service called [Amazon Workmail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/) which you can compare with google apps.

If you're really looking into sending email from an app using SES, you can review [this link](https://mofintodev.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/using-amazon-ses-to-send-email/) which explains how to do it with GoDaddy